# How to get raw image from SteamVR driver

Tags: driver, steam, virtual-reality, openvr

My question is, how could i get the raw image with the help of the driver in order to pass it to the controller software so that it can display the game frames in vr mode.

I looked in the documentations and i found this 
IVROverlay::GetOverlayImageData

Is this the correct way to extract the image buffer?

Comment: Can you give us links to the ressources you found so far? What driver?